# How do I take an image file and convert it into a raster and then access its data?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, raster

How do I take an image file and convert it into a raster and then access its data (RBG values) pixel by pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("lol"));
int rgb = img.getRGB(x, y);

Color c = new Color(rgb);
```

Now you can use Color.getRed(), getGreen(), getBlue() and getAlpha() to get the different values

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(myFilename));
int pixel = image.getRGB(0, 0); // Top left pixel.
// Access the color components, valued 0-255.
int alpha = (pixel >>> 24) & 0xff; // If applicable to image format.
int r = (pixel >>> 16) & 0xff;
int g = (pixel >>> 8) & 0xff;
int b = pixel & 0xff;
```

**[Edit]** Note that @Sibbo's answer is correct and conveniently uses the [`Color` class color accessor methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html); however, extracting the colors directly via bit manipulation as I have demonstrated will likely be considerably faster since it avoids the overhead of repeated constructor calls.

Comment: int r = (pixel >>> 16) & 0xff;
int g = (pixel >>> 8) & 0xff;
int b = pixel & 0xff; what do these lines of code do? and what is the & opereator or the 0xff mean

Comment: @lancegerday: those lines extract the individual color values (r, g, b, a) from the [composite RGBA "pixel" value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) so that you can easily inspect them individual as values between 0 and 255.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ImageIO.read`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29) to read the image file in as a [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), and then use one of the `getData` methods to obtain the image's [`Raster`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html). And therein, you'll find methods to obtain pixel data.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the rgb values after you completed turning the image into a raster use the rasters `.getData` method

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Image img.getRGB(x, y);

Color c = new Color(rgb);
```